# Add styling to an angular custom component

Tags: css, angular, angular-components

I have created a custom angular component e.g. my-component and in its css file i have the following:

```
:host {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 55px;
}
```

Then in some components template i want to use my-component and add some style to it like so:

```
 <my-component class="my-class"></my-component>
```

CSS file:

```
.my-class {
    border-radius: 4px; // NOT WORKING 
    box-shadow: 0 5px 9px 0 rgba(192, 195, 197, 1); // WORKING

    position: relative; // WORKING
    top: 30px; // WORKING
}
```

I cant figure it out why the border-radius is not applied!

Comment: Is it possible that it's being overridden somewhere else in your stylesheet? Does it work with `!important`?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to add border first. Like

```
border: 2px solid black;
```

And then add border radius.

Comment: So i had to add  "overflow: hidden" to the ":host" in order for the component content not to overlaps the border-radius